# Remote Desktop rearranges windows size and position

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, remote-desktop

I have a problem using Remote Desktop connection. When I connect to the computer which is using 2 monitors it works perfectly but the problem appears when I terminate the connection and the problem is that once I disconnect from the connected computer the windows size and position of the opened applications doesnt get remembered or gets rearranged on that computer. This issue only occurs when I try to connect to the computer where it uses 2 monitors or more. Is there any solution to this problem?

Im connecting with a single monitor which has a resolution of 1680 x 1050 and the resolution of the computer that I connected to it is that one monitor is using 2560 x 1440 resolution and the second monitor is using 800 x 600 resolution. Both computers are using Windows 7 Ultimate. Thanks for any help.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to do this natively in Windows 7 that I'm aware of, but there is a third party utility I used to use for that exact purpose called ShellFolderFix.

http://shellfolderfix.en.lo4d.com/

It's a low-resource and very easy to use utility. Hope it helps.